# Trigger click event upon click any place within div borders, not just on inner text click

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have a div:

```
<div id="button">Button Text</div>
```

and jQuery code:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    //do stuff
});
```

Now, the click event is only triggered when the inner text ("Button Text") is clicked, but I want it to be triggered whenever I click any place within the borders of the div. How do I achieve this?

Comment: i would assume, the size of your div, is only the size of your text

Comment: no, it is not. My div is larger than my text.

Comment: that doesn't make any sense then, it should trigger when you click anywhere on the div

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NeeF3/ - works here

Comment: What do you mean by `within the borders of the div`? .Clicked works on every where within its `border`,`padding` or `innertext`.

Comment: It doesn't for me, at number-station.net. How very strange.